# How to filter JSON object array across nested array with in it

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an object array and i am filtering it against property name "username" like this.

```
array =   [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin2",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator2"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "admin3",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator3"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and the filter function is like this

```
  transform(array: any, valueToSearch: string): any[] {

      return array.filter(e => 
       e.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(valueToSearch.toLowerCase()) 
       !== -1);

     }
```

everything works fine, but now i want to filter against the property name "name" in "roles" array in the object. for example i would like to return an object whose "roles" array contains "name" = agent3 , so it should return the whole object which is located at the last in my example. i tried like

```
return agents.filter(e => e.roles.filter(ee => 
       ee.valueToSearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1));
```

but it didn't work.

this is dmeo 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txchxs?embed=1&file=src/app/agentFilter.pipe.ts

Comment: Whether ```valueToSearch```parameter value is ```agent3``` in your example stated in question??

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txchxs?embed=1&file=src/app/agentFilter.pipe.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the example given by you in the question, i was able to change your existing function like this and i hope this is your requirement..

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.transform(this.array,'agent3');
  }

  transform(array: any, valueToSearch: string): any[] {
    return  this.array.filter(e => {
        e.roles.filter(ee => {
          if(ee.name.toLowerCase() === valueToSearch.toLowerCase() ) {
            console.log(e);
            this.finalResult = e;
          }
        })
      })
  }
```

Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzgni7

Comment: your code works fine, but i want a scenario of filter , not search, it only returns object when whole word matches. but i want that when users type a single word it starts to compare and returns suitable value

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txchxs?embed=1&file=src/app/agentFilter.pipe.ts

Comment: that scenario i need

Comment: @RazaEllahi, Whether  this is your expected one?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmzzg7 If you type username then it will filter the data and show the object related to username..

Comment: I want to search by "name" attribute in "roles" array

Comment: So if user types ```sleep``` inside the select box you need to display two results?? Because if he started typing for ```sleep``` then there are two records matches it.. So you need two to show??

Comment: yes all the objects that matches the value, rather it is one or multiple

Comment: @RazaEllahi, Is this is the final result as per your expectation?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmzzg7

Comment: yes this was the result i want, but can we handle the scenario that we can filter across both the attribute "full name" and also with "name" attribute in "roles" array.??

Comment: and i dont want to see the result in json format, i just want to see the filtered list of users showing its name only

Comment: Do you mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctdh7k  Here you can type username and the respective result as per username will be displayed and if you clear it and type name inside role and it will giove the result according..

Comment: If you type sleep then you will get four result as name.. So you want to display the four names inside the roles that match sleep??  But your question asks that the related whole data alone needs to be displayed..

Comment: Yes its nice, but when i type sleep, only john and brick should be listed

Comment: i want the list that can be filtered with two options, from searching by its own "username" or by any "name" attribute in "roles" array. that is if i type, john or just "j". than only list of john should be display. and when i type sleep or just "s" than john and brick should be display

Comment: @RazaEllahi, Change your HTML like this to display username alone ```<div *ngFor="let result of finalResult;">
  {{ result.username }}
  </div>```

Comment: @RazaEllahi, At last you can see all your expectations in this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmzzg7

Comment: no i cant bind the list with "finalresult", it should be bind with the original array

Comment: @RazaEllahi, I am getting more confusion.. Can you clearly mention what is your expected result if you type ```j``` or ```john``` and ```sl``` or ```sleep```??

Comment: i am filtering across username and from id, the same case i need with name attribute in roles array instead of id

Comment: That is what you are getting in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmzzg7 right?? You just type sleep you will get john and brik..

Comment: yes , this was the result i want, thanks so much .i take too much your time, thanks for it

Comment: @RazaEllahi, You should get correct solution as per your actual expectation that is all what i need and i am glad to help you.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```js
myarray =   [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin2",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator2"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "admin3",
    "roles": [{
            "name": "Administrator3"
        },
        {
            "name": "agent3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  

function myFunction(){
    var filtered= myarray.filter((obj)=>{
        return obj.username.match(new RegExp(document.getElementById('search').value,'ig'));
    });
    console.log(filtered);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txchxs?embed=1&file=src/app/agentFilter.pipe.ts

Comment: that scenario i need